# Removing a single item from an enumerable source when the items are equal

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Lets say I have an enumerable source, that looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> source = new [] { "first", "first", "first", "second" };
```

I want to be able to construct a LINQ statement that will return this:

```
"first", "first", "second"
```

Notice how only one of the firsts is gone.  I don't care which one, because in my case all 3 "first"s are considered equal.  I've tried `source.Except(new [] { "first" })` but that strips  all instances out.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to remove duplicates, but only one instance of that duplicate?

Comment: Yep, that's the case.  So far, I've only found things that will remove everything.  I'd like to keep this on IEnumerable<T> without having to use yield return if possible.

Comment: Distinct() method will remove duplicates for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx

Comment: But if you want to remove only one of three "first's" , you may end up writing custom code for it.

Comment: I want to keep the remaining duplicates.  I want to remove one of the instances of "first" and keep the others.  If I apply the same expression to the new enumerable, I want it to remove two of the "first"s.

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan: what?  Why does it matter if you can't think of a use?  I have thought of a use, and I need this operator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
source
  .GroupBy(s => s)
  .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1).DefaultIfEmpty(g.First()))
```

For each group, skip the first element of the group and return the rest - unless that would return none... in that case, return the first element of the group.

---

```
source
  .GroupBy(s => s)
  .SelectMany(g => g.Take(1).Concat(g.Skip(2)))
```

For each group, take the first element, and take from the third element on - always skipping the second element.

Comment: g.Single will raise exception. Replace with g.First() and this will be perfectly elegant (Invalid operation exception : sequence contains more than one element)

Comment: or *var res = source
         .GroupBy(s => s)
         .SelectMany(g => (g.Count() > 1) ? g.Skip(1) : g).ToList();*

Comment: You could also wrap `g.Single()` in a `Lazy` so as to not evaluate it if it's not needed, and to avoid the problem that @RaphaëlAlthaus Mentioned.

Comment: How does this make sure it's disposing the selected value?

Comment: @JNF queries (such as the ones constructed in LINQ) do not modify their source - so the item is not removed, but instead is filtered.  Also, "Dispose" is a very specific term with a very specific meaning (it does not mean Remove).

Comment: @JNF This code is making sure that one instance of each duplicated item is removed.  Since the original question did not mention a "requested value", I was left up to my own to figure out what should be filtered.

Comment: Not quite, the OP gives the example of passing "first" to get rid of an instance of "first". Specifically.

Answer (score 8):

I think Amy B's answer get's you really close, but it will not remove the value in the case where there's only one value there, which is what I think the original poster was looking for.

Here's an extension method that will remove a single instance of the requested item, even if that's the last instance.  This mirrors the LINQ Except() call, but only removes the first instance, not all instances.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ExceptSingle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T valueToRemove)
    {
        return source
            .GroupBy(s => s)
            .SelectMany(g => g.Key.Equals(valueToRemove) ? g.Skip(1) : g);
    }
```

Given: `{"one", "two", "three", "three", "three"}`
The call `source.ExceptSingle("three")` results in `{"one", "two", "three", "three"}`

Given: `{"one", "two", "three", "three"}`
The call `source.ExceptSingle("three")` results in `{"one", "two", "three"}`

Given: `{"one", "two", "three"}`
The call `source.ExceptSingle("three")` results in `{"one", "two"}`

Given: `{"one", "two", "three", "three"}`
The call `source.ExceptSingle("four")` results in `{"one", "two", "three", "three"}`

Comment: This does indeed do exactly what I want.  I ended up using the version I posted as another answer to myself.  Still, have a +1.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a one-liner LINQ statement to do it.  It requires a separate flag variable.  I implemented it as an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ExceptOne<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T element)
{
    var i = 0;

    return enumerable.Where(original => !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(original, element) || ++i > 1);
}
```

I used an int in case I later want to add a "numberToRemove" parameter (change the > 1 to > numberToRemove).  YAGNI and all that, but it was about as readable as a boolean would have been anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<string> source = new [] { "first", "first", "first", "second" };

List<string> newSource = new List<string>();

var foo = source.GroupBy (s => s).Select (s => new KeyValuePair<string,int>(s.Key, (s.Count()>1)?s.Count()-1:s.Count ()));

foreach (var element in foo)
{
    newSource.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(element.Key,element.Value));
}
```

Very quick effort here. Basically, this will create a second list from the original with each distinct key and a count of instances, deduct one if there is more than one, then re-render a list with the right number of elements.

Not as elegant as David B's answer but I'd already written so though I may as well post it as another possible answer. I'm sure the foreach can be made in to a Linq statement but it's late and my brain isn't working!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with LINQ, but here's the general flow you might want to use for this:

Store all unique items in a new list B i.e.:

```
A: {1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 6}
```

becomes

```
B: {1, 2, 4, 6}
```

Iterate through B, removing an instance of it in A if it exists i.e.:

```
A: {1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 6}
```

becomes

```
F: {1, 1, 2, 4, 6}
```

Hope this helps!